# How to make datepicker work with react hook form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-datepicker

I have a short code below, the date picker works fine, it changes when I select other dates.
But i can't figure it out why it always fail in `required` validation even I already select a date.

```
<Controller
    control={control}
    name="disclosureDate"
    rules={{ required: 'This field is required' }}
    errors={errors.disclosureDate}
    value={disclosureDate}
    render={({ field }) => (
      <InputDate
        className="mb-px-8"
        onChange={(value) => setDisclosureDate(value)}
        value={disclosureDate}
      />
    )}
/>
```

I've been following of these links, but I can't make it work in my end.

[react-hook-link-Controllers](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller)

[stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61489188/react-hook-form-controller-issues)

*(by the way, there are other validations aside from `required`, for demonstration purposes only)*

Comment: Hi, can you share a codesandbox please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are using the `Controller` correctly. You should use the `value` and `onChange` it provides in the render prop, try -

```
<Controller
    control={control}
    name="disclosureDate"
    rules={{ required: 'This field is required' }}
    errors={errors.disclosureDate}
    value={disclosureDate}
    render={({ value, onChange }) => (
      <InputDate
        className="mb-px-8"
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
      />
    )}
/>
```